# Merge elements of inner list with outer list

Tags: python-2.7

I have a following list
mylist = ['or', ['or', 'R', ['not', 'B']], 'W']

and wish to remove the double occurrence of 'or' within the list to get the final result as
['or', 'R', ['not', 'B'], 'W']

Comment: Well you can certainly do x = l[1]. extend(l[2:]), but my guess is that doesn't get at the more generic problem you are trying to solve. In general what is your goal?

Comment: I have written a CNF converter and it outputs a list as given the goal in general is to remove the duplicate and/or operations that operate over the same variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive function into a class to remove every repeated string at the first level of your list of lists. This would even clean those strings within greater depth of lists.

class FirstLevelRepeated(object):

```
    def __init__(self,my_list):
        self.mylist=my_list
    def removeRepeated(self):
        for obj_index in range(len(self.mylist)):
            if type(self.mylist[obj_index]) == list:
                self.RemoveRepeated(self.mylist[obj_index])
    def RemoveRepeated(self,actual_object):
        index_to_remove=[]
        for actual_object_index in range(len(actual_object)):
            if type(actual_object[actual_object_index])==list:
                self.RemoveRepeated(actual_object[actual_object_index])
            else:
                if actual_object[actual_object_index] in self.mylist:
                    index_to_remove.append(actual_object_index)
        for index in index_to_remove[::-1]:
            actual_object.pop(index)
        return actual_object


mylist = ['or', ['or', 'R', ['not', 'B']], 'W']
print mylist
list_of_lists=FirstLevelRepeated(mylist)
list_of_lists.removeRepeated()
print list_of_lists.mylist
```